# Passing a String value to a viewbuilder from another view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, viewbuilder

This is the Base View

```
struct BaseView<Content: View>: View {
    @State private var ShowSFView : Bool = false
   
    let content: Content
   
    init(@ViewBuilder content:  () -> Content ) {
        self.content = content()
     
        
    }

//Code for button and URL

}
```

I need to pass two String values to this BaseView , from another View when I call this baseView. One is for button label and other one for URL.

I'am unable to do it from declaring variables on initialiser, getting various errors. How can a
i achieve this?

Edit

Initialiser in baseView

```
init(@ViewBuilder content:  () -> Content , btnlabel: String) {
        self.content = content()
        self.btnlabel=btnlabel
        
    }
```

How I called it from another View

```
 BaseView.init(content: () -> _, btnlabel: "")
```

Comment: What's error are you getting? It can be done by init.

Comment: If I add another string value to init, what should be added as a parameter in place of content: <() -> _> when Iam calling it from second view?

Comment: can you please add the code? which you have tried

Comment: Added the init with one parameter and call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any parameter or string parameter the same as normal init.

```
struct BaseView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State private var ShowSFView : Bool = false
    
    private let content: Content
    
    let stringOne: String
    let stringTwo: String
    
    init(stringOne: String, stringTwo: String, @ViewBuilder content:  () -> Content ) {
        self.content = content()
        self.stringOne = stringOne
        self.stringTwo = stringTwo
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(stringOne)
        Text(stringTwo)
    } 
}
```

Now you can use it like

```
BaseView(stringOne: "str1", stringTwo: "str2") {
    // Content
}
```

**EDIT**

From your example, you can use it like

```
BaseView(content: {
    // Content
}, btnlabel: "Lable")
```

Comment: Thank you so much . Im new to SwiftUI . Only thing I needed was how to call this